# How to get all rows from parse?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm trying this but doesn't work, all I got is a fatal exception

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Cases");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.altam.pasoseguro, PID: 15746
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:265)
at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:268)
at com.example.altam.pasoseguro.MapActivity$3.done(MapActivity.java:223)
at com.example.altam.pasoseguro.MapActivity$3.done(MapActivity.java:219)
at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you are getting an exception, please include the stack trace of the exception in your question.

Comment: What kind of exception? What is this code supposed to do? What is the expected result of running this code?

Comment: `ResourcesNotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2` So it's right there in the error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just trying to Toast the size of the list? If so, you are calling the wrong method.

You are calling

`Toast.makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`

Instead you should be calling

`Toast.makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)`

By doing

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(list.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
```

Comment: Or you can use `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)` (not as clean, but if you want to put any text in the given empty string, then this makes uses of the StringBuilder to automatically build a single string to return after concatenating the parts together)